# React / Jest testing history.push correctly for 100% code coverage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-router, react-testing-library

I have a function in my app as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const Main: React.FunctionComponent<{ data: any[] }> = ({
    data: result }) => {

    const history = useHistory();

    return (
        <>  
            {result?.map(inner => {

                const handleClick = () => {
                    history.push(`/list/${result?.id}`, { item: result?.item})
                }

                return (
                    <div key={result.id} onClick={handleClick}>
                        <div className="inner-content">{result?.content}</div>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </>
    )
}

export default Main;
```

I have a test case in my tests as follows:

```
const mockHandleClick = jest.fn();

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
    useHistory: () => ({
        push: mockHandleClick,
    }),
}));

it('Should test history push', () => {
    let tree = create(<div onClick={mockHandleClick}><div class="inner- 
    content">Content Here</div></div>);
    const button = tree.root.findByType('div')
    button.props.onClick()
    expect(mockHandleClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

This passes, but the `handleClick` function still flags up in the code coverage? so I am not achieving 100% coverage.

Any Idea's?

Comment: Can you update your question to include all relevant code? Can we see the component under test and the `div` the test is targeting? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Updated with component

Comment: Woah... try moving that `handleClick` callback into the main component body so there's only 1 single callback for each mapped `result` element, pass the `id` and `item` into it. See if this improves your coverage.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're having trouble hitting more complete code coverage because you are declaring a `handleClick` callback for each iterated `result` element object. The test appears to only select the first `div`.

Refactor the `handleClick` handler into the component body and pass a single handler to each mapped item and pass the mapped object to the handler.

```
const Main: React.FunctionComponent<{ data: any[] }> = ({
  data: result }) => {

  const history = useHistory();

  const handleClick = (inner) => () => {
    history.push(`/list/${inner?.id}`, { item: inner?.item });
  };

  return (
    <>
      {result?.map(inner => (
        <div key={inner.id} onClick={handleClick(inner)}>
          <div className="inner-content">{inner?.content}</div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```